# Union/Select/GroupBy SQL - Return Items From 1 Email For Each Day That Are Related To Other Items

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, union

I have a big issue with this. It's not an easy thing to do, and I need some help from somebody who is really good with SQL. I tried to make this myself, but after spending a few days, I gave up.
 Here is a table I have:
[image: Table Sample]

This are records from a paypal query (sample).
First I assign an invoice for all Amounts that are greater than 0 (I solved that).
Now I need to make invoices for the refunds, and I have a problem with this, I simply can't make the SQL query (too complex for my knowledge)

Here are the logical steps that the SQL query should do:

1. Get all items with Amount smaller than 0
2. Sort by date
3. Sort by Invoice(we get invoice by using OTID, and finding item with TID=OTID and getting invoice) (but date is most important, and from same day, we sort by invoice)
4. Get Sum of Amount, Amount and Count, Invoice for items FROM SAME DAY, THAT HAVE THE Invoice identical (we get invoice by using OTID, and finding item with TID=OTID and getting invoice)

   We make the sum, only if the Amount is identical.

So for this table, I would need something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the 3rd item has sum amount -12. That's because both items had the same day, and the same invoice, and the same email. If one of the items where from a different date, or invoice, then we would not add them.

I have this sql code so far, that groups things, but I can't seem to find out how to get the invoice, since the relationship is from the same table. So I would need to get invoice by using OTID=TID and getting the invoice.

```
    SELECT SUM(Amount) as AmountS, Count(Amount) as AmountC, Amount, dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, Timestamp)) as Month, Email
FROM Transactions 
WHERE Amount<0 AND Timestamp>'2017/05/14' AND Timestamp<'2017/05/31'
GROUP BY dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, Timestamp)), Amount, Email
ORDER BY Month Asc
```

Help is appreciated :)

Comment: you can only attach the invoice no by a subquery that relates to TID and OTID

Comment: if you sum all the amount of 2017-06-01 it not -88 it is -5. how come? and you reach -88 as your sample result?

Comment: You also have a quantity column which unknown from your sample data even in your sample query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subquery to get the invoice

```
SELECT
  SUM(Amount) AS AmountS,
  COUNT(Amount) AS AmountC,
  Amount,
  DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Timestamp)) AS Month,
  Email,
  (SELECT TOP 1   -- can use TOP, Distinct does not really matter. TOP does not consume much memory than Distinct, or if there is only one unique invoice per transaction then remove TOP
    invoice
  FROM Transactions
  WHERE t.otid = tid)  -- relates T.otid to tid to get the invoice
  AS [INVOICE] 
FROM Transactions t   -- alias as T
WHERE Amount < 0
AND Timestamp > '2017/05/14'
AND Timestamp < '2017/05/31'
GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Timestamp)),
         Amount,
         Email,
         OTID    -- add to group
ORDER BY Month ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error "Column 'Transactions.OTID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: can you please check again

Comment: What I noticed, is that if an item has the same invoice, the same date, the same email, and the same amount, it does not sum it up. Any solution for that?

Comment: can you please post that scenario and what's not summing up

Comment: For example here are the results (consider Name the same thing as Email):  http://sodevrom.net/table3.jpg  . Records 4, 9 and 10 should be grouped. Because they have the same amount, the same name/email, the same date AND the same invoice. It should be 1 record that contains AmountS, AmountC and Amount. Let me know if you know what I mean and if you can help. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: If I remove the (select top 1 ... ) and OTID from group by. It groups the amounts correctly. But it does not show the invoice. Really hope you can help. I think a JOIN is required, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Instead of SELECT in SELECT I used Join:

```
SELECT SUM(t.Amount) AS AmountS, COUNT(t.Amount) AS AmountC, t.Amount,DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, t.Timestamp)) AS Month,t.Name, tt.Invoice
FROM Transactions t  INNER JOIN Transactions tt
ON t.OTID=tt.TID

WHERE t.Amount < 0 AND t.Timestamp > '2017/05/14'
AND t.Timestamp < '2017/05/31' AND t.Invoice IS NULL

GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, t.Timestamp)), t.Amount, t.Name, tt.Invoice
ORDER BY Month ASC, AmountS ASC, Name ASC
```

It works.